# How can I search a range of cells in excel and if they match criteria return with value of another cell in the corresponding row?

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

sorry I am a super novice at all things code and in excel, but I am trying to create a spreadsheet in excel for a small academy. I have a sheet of student information who have enrolled in the academy. On another sheet, Courses, I want to make a very simple visual sheet of the course dates and the students who are in that course. What I would like to do is have this sheet self populate based on the information on the first sheet. For example, the first sheet contains name, email, course, payment received info. And on the Course sheet I would like to create a statement that if the student has successfully enrolled in the course then their name will appear below my header for the course. I used an IF and COUNTIF and was mostly successful but the formula I wrote is not matching the name and course in the same row. How can I edit or rewrite my formula so that way if excel finds the right course then the cell will display the name from the same row?

Here is my formula so far

=IF(COUNTIF(Sales!V4:V100, "March 2-March27"), Sales!A4, "")

Sales!V4:V100 is my cell range with the criteria "March 2-March27" 
Sales!A4 is where one student name is

But I would like to apply this formula to multiple cells, but I cannot manage to get it to input the name from the same row that matched the COUNTIF criteria without manually inputting the correct cell, which defeats the purpose.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Add screenshot to your question with some sample data.

Comment: Consider using a Pivot Table, its easier than it sounds. You can group students by courses (ROW-data).